# Point SVN Externals at a CVS Repository

Tags: svn, cvs, svn-externals, cvs2svn

Is it possible to point an SVN Externals directive at a CVS repository?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it is not possible.

SVN externals simply does an checkout or update on the repository path you give it.  Which doesn't support CVS.

[SVN Book Chapter on Externals](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn-book.html#svn.advanced.externals)

**The only thing you should point at CVS is a gun.. or cvs2svn.**  Long live SVN!

Comment: Thanks, the issue here was that I'd like to link to someone else's CVS repository from my SVN repository, not that I love CVS.

Comment: Yes I understand, we sometimes have to live with old technologies. I just wanted to throw a zinger at CVS. Your best bet is probably to just have a batch file or shell script you can double click to do a check out or update of cvs repo with